# How to sell an ÖBB Nightjet ticket?

Tags: trains, tickets, refunds, austria

We bought two tickets for each of two separate Austrian Railways (ÖBB) Nightjet trains from Amsterdam to Innsbruck. The plan was to decide later which ones we would use. The problem is that we converted the tickets to PDFs, and now can't change them anymore. We've contacted ÖBB, but they don't allow us to make any changes to these tickets. Does anybody know a way to sell one pair of tickets?

Comment: Does the ticket hold your name and the line that restrict its use for just you?

Comment: I guess the answer is going to be no. OBB allows you to postpone downloading the PDF till the last moment, specifically to make changes possible. But once the PDF is downloaded nothing can be done.